# If a function has no critical points then how can I find where the function is increasing or decreasing?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Recently, I have discovered some problems that have no critical points i.e.

$$f'(x) \not = 0$$

For example, if we have the exponential $e^x$ divided by some other function squared i.e. $(x+2)^2$. Then this function will never equal zero. So how can I find where the function is increasing/decreasing?

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, $f'$ gets to zero when $x=0$, so has a critical point there.  Further it is not defined for $x=-2$.  So those are all points where the function could be turning, and you need to check the sign of $f'$ between such points to figure if it is increasing or not...

Comment: @gekkostate Have you posted what the derivative of your function is? $$f'(x) = \dfrac{e^x}{(x + 2)^2}?$$

Comment: Yea, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, $f'(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \neq -2$, since $e^x \gt 0 \forall x$, and $(x + 2)^2 > 0 \forall x \neq -2$

So, save for the behavior of the function at $x =-2$, where it is not defined, the function is always *increasing*. In other words, since we exclude $x = -2$ from the domain of $x$, $f(x)$ is always increasing on the domain on which it is defined.

When there are no values in the domain of a function such that $f'(x) = 0$, then it is always increasing, if $f'(x) \gt 0$, or it is always decreasing, if $f'(x) \lt 0$, since there is no point at which a "transition point" (where $f'(x) = 0$) exists.

Comment: So instead of doing the usual business of finding the critical values, I have to instead look at the denominator and the numerator and see when they become positive/negative right?

Comment: @Macavity: I took the post to be indicating that $f'(x) = \dfrac{e^x}{(x + 2)^2}$, in which case, $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is increasing when $f'(x)>0$ and decreasing when $f'(x)<0$.
The fact it has no critical points just means it doesn't turn around, but the sign of the derivative still gives the information about the growth of the function.